# paste0 vector name to vector values with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, paste

How can I use lapply in the following case.

Cheers
JF

Input list

```
dmx <- list(d2 = c("PT", "16", "0603"),
            d3 = "T")
```

Expected output list

```
dmx2 <- list(c("Dim2=PT", "Dim2=16", "Dim2=0603"),
             "Dim3=T")
```

The objetive is to paste0 "Dim#=" to each values, where # stays for the number in de name of the vector.

Until know I'm using

```
for (i in 1:length(dmx)) {
    dmx[[i]] <- paste0("Dim",substr(names(dmx[i]), 2, 2), "=",  dmx[[i]])
  }
```

But I have noticed that apply functions can be more efficiente.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lapply` with indices or names (but don't expect it's much faster):

Using indices (guaranteed safe):

```
lapply(seq_along(dmx),
       \(x) paste0(sub("d(\\d)", "Dim\\1=", names(dmx)[[x]]), dmx[[x]]))
```

Or using the names directly (might not work in edge cases, but 99/100):

```r
lapply(names(dmx),
       \(x) paste0(sub("d(\\d)", "Dim\\1=", x), dmx[[x]]))
```

You could use your `substr`-expression instead of `sub`. Just showing an `regex`-alternative.

Output:

```r
[[1]]
[1] "Dim2=PT"   "Dim2=16"   "Dim2=0603"

[[2]]
[1] "Dim3=T"
```

Data:

```r
dmx <- list(d2 = c("PT", "16", "0603"),
d3 = "T")
```

---

**Update.** If not for speed we could `stack` and `unstack`:

```r
stack_dmx <- stack(dmx)
stack_dmx$values <- paste0(sub("d(\\d)", "Dim\\1=", stack_dmx$ind), stack_dmx$values)
unstack(stack_dmx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
 imap(dmx, ~ sprintf("%s=%s", str_replace(.y, "d", "Dim"), .x))
```

-output

```
$d2
[1] "Dim2=PT"   "Dim2=16"   "Dim2=0603"

$d3
[1] "Dim3=T"
```

Comment: I like this solution very much.